# Crontab is not running

Tags: cron, ubuntu-mate

I can not figure why this is not running.

I used `crontab -e` for it's creation.

It is owned by me, but the directory it is in is owned by root.

It is located in  `/var/spool/`

There are no cron entries on syslog.

```
# command - The command you want to run. This can contain spaces or point to a bash script.
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# m h  dom mon dow   command
# Run my backup script at 10 a.m every day
0 10 * * * /home/andy/bin/Backup_18_04.sh
# Run my backup script at 8 p.m every day
0 20 * * * /home/andy/bin/Backup_18_04.sh
# Run script EVERY 2 DAYS to cleanup backup directories of older files
0 20 */2 * * /home/andy/bin/Delete_All_But_2_Newest_Files.sh
# Delete date files from /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/
0 20 * * * /home/andy/bin/Delete_All_But_2_Newest_Date_Files.sh
```

Comment: There are two types of crontab: One in /etc, and the other in /var/spool/ created using the `crontab` command. Your description implies the former, but your format is for the latter. The two types have different formats. Wrong format won't work. Please edit your question to clarify the exact path and/or creation method of the crontab.

Comment: Did you check with `journalctl $(type -p cron)`? `service cron status`? `pgrep cron`? Do you `touch /home/andy/Backup.started` near the beginning of your script?

Comment: I did journalctl $(type -p cron). What am I looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my computer was sleeping during the times that the script was scheduled to run. :-)